# WordPress custom search not displaying 'no posts found'

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a custom WordPress search form
it displays the posts matching my input 
however when I search for something not in any of the posts 
for some inputs, it displays the 'no posts found' part 
for other inputs, it displays noting 
absolutely nothing
I add an echo in the if block to see if it is returning an empty array, therefore, displaying noting 
it appears that it is not executing the if block or the else block

```
 if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
        echo '<ul>';
        while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
            $the_query->the_post();
            echo '<li>' . get_the_title() . '</li>';
        }
        echo '</ul>';
    } else {
        echo 'no posts found';
    }
```

Comment: Can you add the code of your query?

Comment: Are you getting any errors? If absolutely nothing is displayed only for some queries, it sounds like there might be a bug somewhere that causes an error and stops the execution of the php (resulting in nothing being displayed.) You can activate debug mode in wp-config.php, that should print out any errors and warnings to the screen. Just remember to turn debug mode off again before you push to the production server. You can also display PHP errors in a particular script only like this: `error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);` Again, remember to remove before you push to live!